# Which algorithm does cake 1.3 use to hash the password?

Tags: hash, passwords, cakephp-1.3

I need to transport the table `users` from cakephp 1.3 to another system but we don't want reset all passwords from users. How does the algorithm work that cakephp 1.3 uses to hash the users' password?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well... I think it was more simple than I thought.

Cake authentication calls **password** method from *Auth* and then calls **hash** from *Security* class.

```
//Auth class
function password($password) {
    return Security::hash($password, null, true);
}
```

In *Security*, by default, it uses **sha1** method with salt and password concatenated; salt is a random string generated during cake installation, his value is written in the **core.php** file.

```
//Security class
function hash($string, $type = null, $salt = false) {
    $_this = Security::getInstance();

    if ($salt) {
        if (is_string($salt)) {
            $string = $salt . $string;
        } else {
            $string = Configure::read('Security.salt') . $string;
        }
    }

    if (empty($type)) {
        $type = $_this->hashType;
    }
    $type = strtolower($type);

    if ($type == 'sha1' || $type == null) {
        if (function_exists('sha1')) {
            $return = sha1($string);
            return $return;
        }
        $type = 'sha256';
    }

    //...
}
```

Then, what I need is take this implementation to the next system and flag the previous users from new users. At first login, users will see a form to enter a new password using the new hash method from new system.